# Caret going next to text rather than the span on contenteditable div

Tags: html, css

When using the contenteditable attribute on a div and have inserted a HTML element span in, for some reason the caret goes inside the space next to the text:

[image]

To replicate, hit backspace to remove the question mark at the end on the example I provided

```css
.pill {
    background-color:  #EEEEEE;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 0px 4px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:0.8em;
    z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<div style="resize:none; overflow: auto; border: none" contenteditable="true">
    is your email still <span class="pill" contenteditable="false">Email</span>?
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the target?

Comment: Why use contenteditable? Wouldn't a simple input elem. prefilled with the email make more sense?

Comment: This is just a simple mockup of a much more complicated example